# Index for a table with multiple JOIN varchar conditions

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm trying to do sort of a matching query to match recording from table A to table B using multiple columns. But for some reason the query is running very slow. I tried to experiment with different index combinations for the joined table but they are not being used, which is why it's always doing a full table scan.

```
SELECT
    nc.id, nc.firstName, nc.lastName, 
    nc.firmName, nc.location,
    nc.city AS city, nc.state AS state, 
    ac.id, ac.lastName, ac.firstName, ac.middleName, 
    IFNULL(ac.suffixName, '') AS suffixName, ac.firmName, ac.city, ac.state
FROM
    NormalContacts AS nc
JOIN
    AllContacts AS ac ON ((nc.firstName = ac.firstName AND nc.lastName = fa.lastName) OR (nc.firstName = fa.middleName AND nc.lastName = ac.lastName))
        AND (ac.city = nc.city AND ac.state = nc.state)
JOIN
    FirmInputTable AS fit ON (fit.firmName = fa.firmName AND fit.otherFirmName = nc.firmName)       
WHERE
    nc.crdNumber IS NULL AND nc.city IS NOT NULL AND nc.state IS NOT NULL AND nc.firmName IS NOT NULL
```

`NormalContacts` is 1,000 records while `AllContacts` is 337,250 records. All fields in the `JOIN` condition are varchar.

Here is the `EXPLAIN` result:

[image]

*fa in the screenshot `AllContacts`, sorry for the typo.

Hope anyone can suggest a way to optimize this query or tell me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us a fiddle please - http://sqlfiddle.com/ . You're likely to get a higher quality response. In particular, show us your indexes.

Comment: You can use fiddle as suggested by J_H. Have you tried using 'use index' to make the optimiser forcefully use the index suggested by you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Optimizer will look at indexes and statistics to decide what order to do the the tables.

In the following, I will assume that `ON` says only how the tables relate to each other and `WHERE` is only for filtering.

The "first" table will probably (but not necessarily) be the one with the most selective `WHERE` condition(s).  So, it's `INDEX` needs to focus on the columns in `WHERE`.  (Sometimes `GROUP BY` or `ORDER BY` come into play.)

The other tables in the `JOIN` sequence will be reached into via "Nested Loop Join".  This is where "for each row in the previous table(s), fetch the row(s) in the current table".  To do this fetch it will use any `WHERE` clauses relevant to the table and any thing in the `ON` that mentions this table (and probably previous tables).  So, think about the `INDEX` for this table from the `WHERE` and `ON` conditions.

Since you cannot always predict what order the Optimizer will walk through the tables, it is best to add index(es) to accommodate each possible order.

A typical shortcut is when `WHERE` mentions only one table.  That table is almost certain to be picked first.

How to build a good index for a particular table, given the `WHERE`/`ON` things leading into it?  See [*my cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

For your case...

You seem to have properly split the `ONs` and `WHEREs` -- Good.

`nc` seems to be the  only table mentioned in `WHERE`, so we can probably assume that the Optimizer will start with it.

`IS NULL` is similar to `= constant`, but `IS NOT NULL` is like a range, not not as easy to optimize.  I recommend

```
nc:  INDEX(crdNumber, state)
```

(Here, I am guessing at which `nc` column is most/least likely to be `NULL`.)

After `nc`, only `ac` (aka `fa`???) could come:

```
ON    ((...) OR (...))
  AND ac.city = nc...
  AND ac.state = nc...
```

`OR` is usually not possible to index or optimize, so we are left with

```
ac:  INDEX(city, state)  -- in either order
```

Possibly `lastName` could be pulled out (after fixing ac/fa) of the `OR`, thereby leading to

```
ac:  INDEX(city, state, firstName)  -- in any order
```

Finally, `fit`:

```
ON    fit.firmName = ...
  AND fit.otherFirmName = ...
```

leads to

```
fit:  INDEX(firmName, otherFirmName)  -- in either order
```

*Please* fix the `fa` in the query; then I will modify my answer if needed.

Note:  `INDEX(a,b)` is *better* than `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` in cases like these.

Comment: Awesome! My query that was running for a minute or two, now only takes 1-3 seconds. I thought it was the `OR` condition making it slow so I kept trying to make indexes for `firstName`, `lastName`, and `middleName` but failed. Turns out I don't need to and just need to add indexes for `city` and `state`. Thanks a lot for the recommended indexes! :D